# How to start a Docker container as fast as possible?

Tags: docker, performance

Consider the following command line (running on Ubuntu):

```bash
docker run --network=host phw"
```

The container it references prints "Hello World" and exits:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
ADD main.py .
CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
# Python script prints Hello World and exits.
```

Besides not using Python for this use case, **how can I make this run as fast as possible?**

### Example timings

A parameter-less `docker run` clocks in at 977.8ms.

```bash
❯   hyperfine "docker run phw"  
Benchmark 1: docker run phw
  Time (mean ± σ):     977.8 ms ±  54.0 ms    [User: 9.4 ms, System: 44.7 ms]
  Range (min … max):   886.2 ms … 1059.6 ms    10 runs
```

With [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/), it is 2.4x faster!

```bash
❯   hyperfine "docker run --network=host phw"
Benchmark 1: docker run --network=host phw
  Time (mean ± σ):     407.4 ms ±  25.8 ms    [User: 1.6 ms, System: 51.6 ms]
  Range (min … max):   372.0 ms … 449.4 ms    10 runs
```

What else can I do? And what are the tradeoffs?

Comment: If you haven't, run docker on linux. Docker is native there. Everywhere else it has to jump through a bunch of crazy hoops to launch.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is running on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS).

Comment: Then next would probably to find a more lightweight docker image. Debian is heavy. Looks like Python has alpine images: https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: If you're on a Linux host anyways, use the Python that's probably preinstalled on your host system.  Also try to run fewer longer-lived containers, rather than putting a container startup in your application's critical path.

Comment: @Evert For this case I'm not clear that the underlying distribution will matter.  The image has already been pulled, and the copy-on-write filesystem should be independent of the image size.

Comment: @DavidMaze, imagine the use case is similar to (but not exactly) running user-provided Python code. We need to run in a container to sandbox it. Hence why we need to run each invocation in a new container, and throw away the file system at the end of the run. Or maybe there's another way to do this?

Comment: If speed is important, avoid `docker` and use one of the lower level tools [like `runc`](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/you-dont-need-an-image-to-run-a-container/) that lets you define containers with (or without) specific components.